# Queries related to APNS

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have gone through Apple document on APNS but still I have some queries related to APNS. In my application I want to give user option to register/un-register for Remote Notification i.e.

1. When user launch app for the first time, app will ask user to register for notification. When user click on Register button my app will call registerForRemoteNotification method and receive device token. This is fine.
2. If user has registered for notification my app will display option to un-register for notification. When user click Un-Register it should un-register the user and my server will remove that device token from database and next time it should not send notification to user. That's also fine. So when I launch my app again it will ask for registration again since it has un-registered.
3. My problem is what will happen if user uninstall the app.Suppose user has registered for Notification and then it uninstall the app and install within a day or so. When user again install the app my app will ask for registration but at the same time receive pending notifications, since on Apple my token is still valid.
4. Another issue is what happen if user change the settings of app in Notification Center to not receive any notification.In that case also Apple will add device token to list in feedback service?

Is my scenario valid?How should I manage this? Or it is fine if I receive pending notification but my app won't receive new notification.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Apple allows only up to one notification in the queue per app. This means if a new push message is sent while the previous one is still in the queue, it will be replaced. There should never be a list of pending notifications with regards to scenario 3.

Comment: Yes I know, and what I mean by pending notification is the latest undelivered notification only.

Comment: Ah, I guess I understood you wrongly then. With regards to point 4 *I think* Apple will try to send the next notification, but the device will reply it won't accept anymore notifications. **After that happens** Apple should have the device added to the feedback service.